# How to work with a HikariCP connection pool?

Tags: activejdbc

How do I get activejdbc working with a HikariCP connection pool? Mostly want this for documentation purposes.

I've tried a few different methods but none have worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for postrgresql:

```
public static final HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
    HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig();
    hc.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
    hc.setJdbcUrl(DataSources.PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    hc.setUsername(DataSources.PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
    hc.setPassword(DataSources.PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
    hc.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
    return hc;
}

public static final HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig());

public static final void dbInit() {
    Base.open(hikariDataSource); // get connection from pool
}

public static final void dbClose() {
    Base.close();
}
```